What does the "stealth boy" Power armor mod actually do in Fallout The Role-playing game by Modiphus?
On page 145 of the core rulebook of Fallout The Roleplaying Game, one of the "torso" mods listed for power armor is "Stealth Boy". Its description is:

You may activate a stealth boy (pg.171) once per scene by spending 1 charge.

But what does this actually mean? You can always activate a stealth boy using a minor action if you have one. Does "may activate a stealth boy once per scene" mean:
A. Activate an ability equivalent to a stealth boy without having to physically use one, instead turning your fusion core charges into stealth boys (This is INCREDIBLY POWERFUL if true)
OR
B. Once per scene you can activate one of the stealth boys in your inventory without having to spend the minor action to do so (which is merely an OK ability saving you one minor action any time you use a stealth boy once/scene)
OR
C. BOTH (once per scene you gain the benefit of a stealth boy for 3 rounds without using a stealth boy or an action, possibly being the most broken power armor mod in the game)?
OR
D. NOTHING, as reading the words literally, this allows you to do something (Activate a stealth boy) once per scene which you could already do anyway without this ability (and more oftne then this too), and the ability does not mention anything about requiring less actions or consumables.
I would like to think the game designers did not intend D., so which of A, B or C did they intend?

There's one more OR. Are you sure you even can use stealth boy when wearing Power Armor without this mod?

@Mołot nothing in its description nor in the power armor description preventing it that I can see. In the games you can use it while wearing power armor too, so that is probably not the intention.

@mxyzplk that's good to know. I never modded my pwoer armor that much in the games.

It is not offical, but based on an answer on the fallout RPG errata forum the answer appears to be A:

I read it as “once per scene you may use a minor action to activate
the built in stealth boy, this consumes one charge from the fusion
core”

This is consistent with how it works in the Fallout 4 video game so this must be the RAI here.

Can you link the forum answer? Ideally with an archival link that will preserve it even if the forum goes kaput?

sure I will add that thanks

“Based on both comments here” I’m not sure what this is referring to.

both comments here and on the forum. THe comment here specifically is the one above by mxyzplk which I can see my response to but not the comment anymore, basically says the same thing as the forum, that the videogame works like A.

I will jsut remove the mention of the comment here since it seems to have been deleted

Can you quote the relevant forum post here so this isn’t a “link only” sort of non-answer.
